# Cannot associate a name with uid 1234

Tags: linux, email

How would one send a mail from a batch script using a *virtual* user (uid number is not present in /etc/passwd) ?

Currently it keeps on failing with:

```
$ mail -s "my subject" foobar@example.com
Cannot associate a name with uid 1234
```

Comment: Try: mail -v -s "my subject" foobar@example.com

Comment: Would be nice to take a look on the code http://sourcecodebrowser.com/nail/12.1/v7_8local_8c_source.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call `sendmail` directly.  Just build out the complete email message including headers, and then send it through `sendmail -t`.  the `-t` tells sendmail to read the headers from the message itself for the required information.

```
---start of mail.txt---
date: now
to: foobar@example.com
subject: My Subject 
from: your-email@example.com

body of message.....
---end of mail.txt----
```

then

```
 /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < mail.txt
```

or you can just open a pipe , and echo the contents of the message into the pipe

`| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t`

Comment: I could never get this to work using postfix & bsd-mailx. I simply cannot switch the whole system to sendmail.

Comment: postfix should provide the sendmail compatibility command?  http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html